# How to add components node in Xamarin Android project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

In VS 2015 I am unable to find components node in my solution structure.
I need it to add sqlite.net.
Can anybody help me to know the procedure for adding components.

Attached is the image.

[image: solution]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same package from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/). The Xamarin Component Store is being [phased out](https://blog.xamarin.com/hello-nuget-new-home-xamarin-components/) in favor of NuGet.